# How to prove that $L^p [0,1]$ isn't induced by an inner product? for $p\neq 2$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, inner-products, lp-spaces

I'd like to know how could I prove that $L^p [0,1]$ isn't induced by an inner product? (For $p\neq 2$, including $p=\inf$).

It is clear to me that I would need to find two functions $f$, $g$ in $L^p$ that would not fulfill the parallelogram-law.

I'm having trouble finding these functions (for both finite and infinite cases).
Could you guide me how to find such functions? what intuition is there for these kind of questions? What would be special about them?

Any guidenss would be blessed.
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything for $f$ and $g$?

Comment: What about $\mathbb{1}_{[0,1/2]}$ and $\mathbb{1}_{[1/2,1]}$?

Comment: @Daniel McLaury
I actually tried some trivial but it didn't turn out so well.
Do i get that "almost every" functions f,g would do? why is that, intuitivly?

Krokop:
Thanks. if i'm correct, this example works for any p>1 including inf, but not for p=1. am i right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll give you a hint.

Let $$f(x)=\begin{cases}2,x\in[0,3/4],\\0,x>3/4,\end{cases}\quad g(x)=f(1-x).$$

Then the parallelogram law says that in hilbert spaces we have
$$2\|f\|^2+2\|g\|^2=\|f-g\|^2+\|f+g\|^2.$$

Can you calculate the norms above?

Comment: The equation doesn't hold for p=2!

Comment: @Teodorism what do you mean?

Comment: Isn't $L^2[0,1]$ an inner-product space?

Comment: Is $L^p[0,1]$ the set of $p-$integrable functions in [0,1]?

Comment: @Teodorism it is. But the author explicitly asked about the case $p \ne 2$

Comment: I understand. But if $L^2$ is an inner-product space then the parallelogram identity should hold for all $f,g\in L^p[0,1]$ including yours.

Comment: @Teodorism exactly

Comment: The identity doesn't hold for your $f,g$ when $p=2$.

Comment: I was wrong. It does hold for $p=2$.

Answer (score 10):

For the case in which $1 \leq p < \infty$:

Let $\displaystyle f = \bigg( \frac{1}{\mu(A)} \bigg)^{1/p} \cdot \chi_A$ and $\displaystyle g = \bigg( \frac{1}{\mu(B)} \bigg)^{1/p} \cdot \chi_B$ where $A, B$ both have nonzero finite measure, are disjoint and $\chi$ is the indicator function.

Notice that $$\|f\|_p = \bigg( \int \vert f \vert^p \, d\mu \bigg)^{1/p} = \bigg( \int \frac{1}{\mu(A)} \chi_A \, d\mu \bigg)^{1/p}  = \bigg( \int_A \frac{1}{\mu(A)} \, d\mu \bigg)^{1/p} = 1$$ and similarly $\|g\|_p = 1$.

Observe that

$$\begin{align*}
\|f + g\|_p&= \bigg( \int \vert f + g \vert^p \, d\mu \bigg)^{1/p} \\
&=\bigg( \int \bigg \vert \bigg( \frac{1}{\mu(A)} \bigg)^{1/p} \cdot \chi_A + \bigg( \frac{1}{\mu(B)} \bigg)^{1/p} \cdot \chi_B \bigg \vert^p \, d\mu \bigg)^{1/p} \\
&= \bigg( \int \frac{1}{\mu(A)} \chi_A + \frac{1}{\mu(B)} \chi_B \, d\mu \bigg)^{1/p} \\
&= \bigg( \int_A \frac{1}{\mu(A)} \, d\mu + \int_B \frac{1}{\mu(B)} \, d\mu \bigg)^{1/p} \\
&= 2^{1/p}
\end{align*}$$

**Note**: We use the fact that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint and get $\chi_A \cdot \chi_B = 0$ when moving from line 2 to line 3 above.

Similar reasoning shows $\|f - g\|_p = 2^{1/p}$.

Recall that in an inner product space, the Parallelogram law holds: $\|f + g\|_p^2 + \|f - g\|_p^2 = 2 \|f\|_p^2 + 2 \|g\|_p^2$.

But $\|f + g\|_p^2 + \|f - g\|_p^2 = 2 \cdot 2^{2/p}$ and $2 \|f\|_p^2 + 2 \|g\|_p^2 = 4$ which means that we must have $2^{2/p} = 2$ which only happens if $p = 2$.

For the case in which $p = \infty$:

Let $f = \chi_A$ and $g = \chi_B$ where $A, B$ are disjoint and both have nonzero measure.

Notice that $\|f\|_\infty = \|g\|_\infty = 1$ and $\|f + g\|_\infty = \|f - g\|_\infty = 1$. The Parallelogram Law doesn't hold because $\|f + g\|_\infty^2 + \|f - g\|_\infty^2 = 2$ but $ 2 \|f\|_\infty^2 + 2 \|g\|_\infty^2 = 4$

Comment: This solution is the best here, since it doesn't use the fact that $X=[0, 1]$. It can be easily extended to the case when $(X, \mu)$ is an abstract measure space which contains two disjoint sets $A, B$ of positive measure.

Answer (score 5):

*How to find these...*

By linearity of the integral one has:
$$\mathrm{supp}f\cap\mathrm{supp}g=\varnothing:\quad\int|f\pm g|^p\mathrm{d}\lambda=\int|f|^p\mathrm{d}\lambda+\int|g|^p\mathrm{d}\lambda$$

So take a block and shift it slightly:
$$f:=\chi_{[0,1]}:\quad f_\varepsilon(x):=f(x-\varepsilon)$$

Then for an appropriate choice:
$$\|f+f_\varepsilon\|_p^2+\|f-f_\varepsilon\|_p^2\neq2\|f\|_p^2+2\|f_\varepsilon\|_p^2$$

*...besides, this idea should work for any nontrivial function not only blocks.*