# Parallelogram law in L1 space - Did not understand counter-example

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, inner-products

[Parallelogram law in $L_1$ space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1379254/parallelogram-law-in-l-1-space)
In this topic they gave a counter-example to the title.
My problem is, their counter-example is wrong!
if you find the norm of:
$||f-g||$ by their norm, you will receive 0!
Thus the equality is True!
They dont get $2 \ne 1$, they get $1=1$.
Am I right? please check the norm there, I will add my calculation even to prove it!
$$\left(\int _0^1\left(f\left(x\right)+g\left(x\right)\right)dx\right)^2=(\int _0^{\frac{1}{2}}f\left(x\right)dx-\int _{\frac{1}{2}}^1g\left(x\right)dx)^2=(\int _0^{\frac{1}{2}}1dx-\int _{\frac{1}{2}}^11dx)^2=\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\left(0\right)^2=0$$
and as you can see from my calculation, it is not equal to $1$!!.
Please tell me what am I doing wrong \ are they wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: Where does the minus sign for the second integral come from?

Comment: Oh sorry, it should be minus on both integral, since the norm is $f(x)-g(x)$. and there should be a square on both also, my bad ( I added it later on )

Comment: Which example are you referring to ? In the approved answer they have $f(x) := 1_{[0,1/2]}(x) \qquad \text{and} \qquad g(x) := 1_{[1/2,1]}(x)$.

Comment: Exactly, this one.

Comment: I calculated the norm of these both, but in $||f(x)-g(x)||$ I got 0 ( as above )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\|f-g\|$ is not $\int (f(x)-g(x))dx$. It is $\int |f(x)-g(x)|dx$ which is equal to $1$.

Comment: How, I dont see it happening... please tell me how I get 1.
By my calculations, they are negativing each other. since they both has half in different parts, so the intergral will still be 0

Comment: @BenShaines On $(0,\frac 1 2 )$ you get $|f(x)-g(x)|=|1-0|=1$. On $(\frac 1 2,1 )$ you get $|f(x)-g(x)|=|0-1|=1$.

Comment: How, but its not true with the integral. you need to have integral, not |f(x)-g(x)|
if you have integral, it should be half. not 1 ( and they both has half so one )

Comment: Integral from $0$ to $\frac  1 2$ (of $|f(x)-g(x)|$) is $\frac 1  2 $. The integral from $\frac 1  2$ to $1$ is also $\frac 1  2$. They add up to $1$. @BenShaines

Comment: If you get $\|f-g\|=0$ for two different functions $f$ and $g$ you are doing something wrong. Check your calculation calmly and slowly.  @BenShaines

Comment: I really dont know... could it be because of the absolute value? I will try it one minute, I might have forgotten it.

Comment: Oh I am an idiot, I forgot to add absolute value.. that is my only mistake, forgot the integral should have absolute value.