# How to show the parallelogram law holds in $L^p$ (or $l^p$) if and only if $p=2$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, geometry, measure-theory

Parallelogram law: $$||x+y||^2+||x-y||^2=2||x||^2+2||y||^2.$$ 
How to show this statement? I tried to prove the $l^p$ case. But it seems not easy to manipulate these norms since they have power and summation signs.

Comment: Use the fact the norms in $L^p$ (and in $\ell^p$) have an associated inner product. to prove the $L^p$ case and consider a bit why this would fail otherwise. In what context are you being asked to prove this statement? I see a measure theory tag -- is this an intro level course in measure theory?

Comment: For a complete proof see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/997292/how-to-prove-that-lp-0-1-isnt-induced-by-an-inner-product-for-p-neq-2), but you should try to solve the problem only using one of the answers giving a hint, not a full solution

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I'm taking a measure theory course. And there is an exercise in the book that asks if the parallelogram law hold for $L^p$ if $p\not =2$. I searched some answers online and I guess the statement in my question is correct, but people mainly give counterexamples.

Answer (score 5):

Take $f=I_{(0,1/2)},g=I_{(1/2,1)}$ and compute all the 4 terms. You will see that parallelogram law holds iff $2^{1-2/p}=1$ which means $p=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider two simple functions:

$f(x) = I_{[a, (a + b)/2]}$

$g(x) = I_{[(a + b)/2, b]}$

We can see that the parallelogram law won’t hold for $p \ne 2$:

$\| f - g \|_p^2 + \| f + g \|_p^2$

$= (\int_{[a, b]} |f(x)-g(x)|^p dx)^{2/p} + (\int_{[a, b]} |f(x)+g(x)|^p dx)^{2/p}$

$= (\int_{[a, b]} 1 dx)^{2/p} + (\int_{[a, b]} 1 dx)^{2/p}$

$= 2(b-a)^{2/p}$

$\ne 2^{-\frac{2}{p} + 1}2(b-a)^{2/p}$

$= 2^{-\frac{2}{p} + 2}(b-a)^{2/p}$

$= 2((\frac{b-a}{2})^{2/p} + (\frac{b-a}{2})^{2/p})$

$= 2((\int_{[a, b]} f(x) dx)^{2/p} + (\int_{[a, b]} g(x) dx)^{2/p})$

$= 2((\int_{[a, b]} |f(x)|^p dx)^{2/p} + (\int_{[a, b]} |g(x)|^p dx)^{2/p})$

$= \|f\|_p^2 + \|g\|_p^2$

Indeed this equality will only occur for $1 = 2^{-2/p}\cdot 2 \iff p = 2$.